# Angular JS multiple errors

Tags: angularjs

This is my situation:

I setted up angular on HTML5 mode for urls, then, I'm using this .htaccess to handle the urls:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

When I load pages like `/home` or `/gallery` it's all ok, but when I try to load the page `/page/name`, the whole app completely frozen, and I get those errors on the console:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular.js:6314:34)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular.js:5718:15)
at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular.js:5627:30)
at link (http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular-route.js:916:7)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular.js:6311:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular.js:5722:15)
at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular.js:5627:30)
at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular.js:5741:21)
at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular.js:6332:18)
at update (http://localhost:8888/lib/angular/angular-route.js:866:25) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

and then a loop of those errors:

```
<error> VM48:146
InjectedScript.wrapObject VM48:146
(anonymous function) angular.js:9509
(anonymous function) angular.js:6950
nodeLinkFn angular.js:6314
compositeLinkFn angular.js:5722
publicLinkFn angular.js:5627
boundTranscludeFn angular.js:5741
[much more errors like those, loop]
```

Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Those errors come from Angular and as such, won't have anything to do with your server configuration. At a guess, I'd say you've got a routing loop or something similar. Show your route config

Comment: There is some error with the route configuration. Can you post your config block?